# How do I get the variable and Increment to reset?

Tags: javascript, variables

```
    var fredclicknumber=0;
$(".fredinbed").click(function(){
    if(fredclicknumber==0) {
        $(".fredtext").addClass("txtbxin")
        $(".fredtext").removeClass("txtbxout")
    }
    else if (fredclicknumber==1){
        $(".fredtext").addClass("txtbxout")
        $(".fredtext").removeClass("txtbxin")
    }
    ++fredclicknumber;//

})
if(fredclicknumber > 1){
    fredclicknumber=0;
}
```

Im trying to create a text box that will appear if you click the item, and disappear when clicked again, however with the code shown,It only goes through this process once, what I want to do is somehow loop this code so you can make the text box appear and disappear any number of times.

Comment: Looks like you want to use a boolean instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are just toggling between class , you can use [toggleclass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of creating a variable

```js
$(".fredinbed").click(function() {
  $(".fredtext").toggleClass("txtbxout")
})
```

```css
.txtbxin {
  color: green
}

.txtbxout {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='fredinbed'>Toggle</button>
<span class='fredtext txtbxin'>Toggle class </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggleClass jQuery funtion instead of checking and changing variable values.

```
$(".fredinbed").click(function(){
     $(".fredtext").toggleClass("txtbxin");
     $(".fredtext").toggleClass("txtbxout");
});
```

So, if class already assign to element than toggleClass will remove it, otherwise it will add class.

Answer (score 0):

Use .toggleClass('is-show')

https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

It will look like this

```
$(".fredinbed").click(function(){
  $(".fredtext").addClass("is-show")
})
```